# How to achieve ImageAlign.MiddleCenter in the overriden OnPaint method

Tags: c#, onpaint

As the subject line explains it.

I want to achieve the behaviour **ImageAlign.MiddleCenter** in the Image property of a Button 
control in .NET

i am overriding the Button's OnPaint event. 
I use **e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image,oDrawRectagle);**
to paint the image inside the Button control.
However this always appears on the Lefthand side of the Button.
Since the oDrawRectagle always returns the 0,0 co-ordinates for the ClientRectangle.

I want the image to be always aligned **ImageAlign.MiddleCenter**. How do i achieve it ?

Thanks

```
  protected override void  OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                 Graphics g = e.Graphics;

                 int iHeight;
                 int iWidth;

                 if (Image != null)
                 {
                     //newSize = MaintainAspectRatio(Image, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);
                     //iHeight = newSize.Height;
                     //iWidth = newSize.Width;
                     Rectangle ResizedRectangle = MaintainAspectRatio(Image,ClientRectangle);
                     iHeight = ResizedRectangle.Height;
                     iWidth = ResizedRectangle.Width;

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     iWidth = ClientRectangle.Width;
                     iHeight = ClientRectangle.Height;
                 }

                 g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(213, 221, 224)), ClientRectangle);

                 // Draw border
                 Color oLeftTopColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
                 Color oRightBottomColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
                 Pen oLeftTopPen = new Pen(oLeftTopColor);
                 Pen oRightBottomPen = new Pen(oRightBottomColor);
                 // top line
                 g.DrawLine(oLeftTopPen, 0, 0, iWidth - 1, 0);
                 //g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlLight), 1, 1, iWidth-2, 1);
                 // bottom line
                 g.DrawLine(oRightBottomPen, 0, iHeight, iWidth - 1, iHeight);
                 //g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark), 1, iHeight-2, iWidth-2, iHeight-2);
                 // right line
                 g.DrawLine(oRightBottomPen, iWidth, 0, iWidth, iHeight - 1);
                 //g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark), iWidth-2, 1, iWidth-2, iHeight-2);
                 // left line
                 g.DrawLine(oLeftTopPen, 0, 0, 0, iHeight - 1);
                 //g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlLightLight), 1, 1, 1, iHeight-2);

                 // Draw image
                 if (Image != null)
                 {
                     //Rectangle oDrawRectagle = new Rectangle(
                     //   8, 5, iWidth - 20, iHeight - 10);
                     Rectangle oDrawRectagle = new Rectangle(
                        0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
                     if (Enabled == false)
                     {
                         e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, oDrawRectagle,
                            0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height,
                            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image,oDrawRectagle);

                     }
                 }

                 // Draw text
                 if (Text != null)
                 {
                     int iTextTop = 5;
                     int iTextLeft = 5;
                     int iMaxTextWidth = iWidth - 10;
                     int iMaxTextHeight = iHeight - 10;
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just manually change the position to the center using the button size and the image size.

```
oDrawRectangle = new Rectangle(this.Width / 2 - iWidth / 2, this.Height / 2 - iHeight / 2, iWidth, iHeight);
```